# New to regex - retrieve a question mark

Tags: python, regex

I am quite new to regex and I would like to know if there was a way to match something that is either a normal character : `\w+` or a question mark. I am trying to retrieve the value after the `n`.

The line has this format :

`n : ?, t : 0.4`

The thing that follows n can also be an integer :

`n : 3, t : 0.7`

So far I have :

```py
import re
line = "n : 4, t : 0.4"
value = re.findall(r'\w : (\w+), \w : \d\.\d+', line)
```

How can I change this to take into account the fact that `line` can contain a question mark ?

Expected output :

- if following `n` is a ?, value should be None
- if following `n` is an integer, value should be that integer

Comment: For a digit or a `?`, `[\d?]`

Comment: Using your regex: `\w : (?:\w+|\?), \w : \d\.\d+`

Comment: The question mark is really a question mark in my ```.txt``` file. If it's not then it's an integer

Comment: try regex101.com, this website gives some more context and room to play with things. Note that you need to set it python first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the "Alternate" regex symbol.

Your regex should therefore be: `\w : (\w+|\?), \w : \d\.\d+`.
Do not forget to escape the question mark, since it is also a regex symbol.

EDIT: If the value following `n` must be either an integer or a `?`, you can use `\d` to match a digit, and `\d+` to match a number (with multiple digits). Your regex would become `\w : (\d+|\?), \w : \d\.\d+`